# Converting meshes to metaballs

Tags: mesh, blobs, voxels, volume-rendering

I'm doing a project where I need to convert an existing polygonal mesh into a static shape made from metaballs (blobs). I have voxelized the mesh with binvox to "a .raw file" (according to the description at [binvox](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~min/binvox/)), but I have no clue of how it stores the data, and therefore don't know how to load it.

Question1: Is there any non PHD way to do so? Create a metaball model from a polygonal mesh.
Question2: Has anyone ever used the said .raw file format from binvox and if you did, how?

Comment: For what does PHD stand?

Comment: PhD.. as in very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

RLE Run length Encoding
The binary voxel data

The binary data consists of pairs of bytes. The first byte of each pair is the value byte and is either 0 or 1 (1 signifies the presence of a voxel). The second byte is the count byte and specifies how many times the preceding voxel value should be repeated (so obviously the minimum count is 1, and the maximum is 255).

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~min/binvox/binvox.html